# How to send POST request to some website using winapi?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, post

I'd like to send HTTP POST request to website and retrieve the resultant page using winapi. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MSDN docs have sample code using WinHTTP:

- [IWinHttpRequest::Send Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384045(VS.85).aspx)
- [Posting Data to the Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384270(VS.85).aspx#Posting_data_to_the_)

Answer (score 2):

Also consider using something like [Libwww](http://www.w3.org/Library/) or [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use Winsock (basically the Windows version of Berkeley sockets), create & send the HTTP request and receive & parse the response.